# Angular8 - How to position the select element on edited object

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem with showing the correct edited value in select element. When select contain simple list with id and name then it works fine when the select operates on objects it does't.

I mean something like this:

```html
<div class="dropdown" dropdown>
    <select class='select-option dropdown-list form-control' formControlName="subjectId" id="subjectId">
        <!-- [selectedIndex]="selectedSubject.id"> -->
        <option *ngFor="let subject of schoolSubjects" [ngValue]="subject" class="option">{{subject.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <span *ngIf="syllabiForm.controls.subjectId.touched && syllabiForm.controls.subjectId.errors?.required"
        class="text-danger">Syllabi Subject cannot be blank.</span>
</div>
```

in this case subjectId is an object. Select element works fine and picks the selected object properly but do not position on that particular one in edit mode althought the value is there. What is the trick to "force" select element to show the right value. Right now it is always empty.

Here is the code populating the form in edit mode:

```js
this.syllabiForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(this.editedSyllabi.name, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(45)]),
    subjectId: new FormControl(this.editedSyllabi.subjectId, []),
    id: new FormControl(this.editedSyllabi.id, []),
    active: new FormControl(this.editedSyllabi.active, []),
    deleted: new FormControl(this.editedSyllabi.deleted, [])
});
```

Comment: I don't understand... you have object in select, but when you assign subject id, it's a number (string?). that is what I assume `this.editedSyllabi.subjectId` is? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: When you use a simple list with `id`, your `formControlName` works because it is initialized with an `id` too. But when you use an object, you will need to modify your `formControl` and initialize it with an object instead. If you still aren't able to figure out the issue, please provide more info, like a sample object from `schoolSubjects` or better yet, create a StackBlitz

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no time to create example in StackBlitz, it would take some time for me, especially that I never user that before :)  In terms of formControl init, it is initialized with object already, it is in my example snippet: subjectId: new FormControl(this.editedSyllabi.subjectId, []), - subjectId is the object, not an ID, the name matches the database field and that's why it is called subjectId.

Answer (score 0):

To populate the form with edited data, you need to use **patchValue**

Try like this :

```
this.syllabiForm.patchValue(this.editedSyllabi);
```

Comment: Well, I think this is just another way to populate the form, my way is not wrong one, it's just an old way I think. The point is that both ways do not position a dropdown select element on the right edited value which comes from the this.editedSyllabi. My dropdown still shows nothing in edit mode, I can then choose a "new value" or the same one and save the data but I have to do it manually, the value doesn't select itself automatically when the form opens.